# My ML.Net recommendation algorithm returns 0 for both RSquared and Root Mean values

Tags: c#, ml.net

I'm new to machine learning, but I have experience in C# which is why I want to pick up Ml.net as a way to familiarize myself with the topic.

As i'm grasping the concept, I have decided to make a beer recommendation model which will take previous reviews and recommend a new beer.

Anyway, when I run the program, the values returned in the EvaluateModel below return 0 each. I'd love another pair of eyes on this. Thanks!

This is the training model

```
public static ITransformer BuildAndTrainModel(MLContext mlContext, IDataView trainingDataView)
        {
            IEstimator<ITransformer> estimator = mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "abvEncoded", inputColumnName: "abv")
                                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "ibuEncoded", inputColumnName: "ibu"))
                                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: "beerIDEncoded", inputColumnName: "beerID"))
                                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "nameEncoded", inputColumnName: "name"))
                                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "styleEncoded", inputColumnName: "style"))
                                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "breweryIDEncoded", inputColumnName: "breweryID"))
                                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: "userIDEncoded", inputColumnName: "userID"))
                                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "abvEncoded", "ibuEncoded", "styleEncoded"));

                        var options = new MatrixFactorizationTrainer.Options
            {
                MatrixColumnIndexColumnName = "userIDEncoded",
                MatrixRowIndexColumnName = "beerIDEncoded",
                LabelColumnName = "Label",
                NumberOfIterations = 20,
                ApproximationRank = 100
            };

            var trainerEstimator = estimator.Append(mlContext.Recommendation().Trainers.MatrixFactorization(options));

            Console.WriteLine("=============== Training the model ===============");
            ITransformer model = trainerEstimator.Fit(trainingDataView);

            return model;
```

This is the Evaluate model

```
public static void EvaluateModel(MLContext mlContext, IDataView testDataView, ITransformer model)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("=============== Evaluating the model ===============");
            var prediction = model.Transform(testDataView);

            var metrics = mlContext.Regression.Evaluate(prediction, labelColumnName: "Label", scoreColumnName: "Score");

            Console.WriteLine("Root Mean Squared Error : " + metrics.RootMeanSquaredError.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("RSquared: " + metrics.RSquared.ToString());
        }
        public static void UseModelForSinglePrediction(MLContext mlContext, ITransformer model)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("=============== Making a prediction ===============");
            var predictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<Beers, BeerPrediction>(model);

            //Predict
            var beerSample = new Beers()
            {
                userID = 1,
                abv = ".08",
                ibu = "120",
                beerID = 379,
                name = "Heady Topper",
                style = "American",
                breweryID = 272,
                ounces = 16
             };
            var beerRatingPrediction = predictionEngine.Predict(beerSample);

            if (Math.Round(beerRatingPrediction.Score, 1) > 3.5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Beer " + beerSample.beerID + " is recommended for user " + beerSample.userID);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Beer " + beerSample.beerID + " is not recommended for user " + beerSample.userID);
            }
        }
```

The main

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MLContext mLContext = new MLContext();

            (IDataView trainingDataView, IDataView testDataView) = LoadData(mLContext);

            ITransformer model = BuildAndTrainModel(mLContext, trainingDataView);

            EvaluateModel(mLContext, testDataView, model);

            UseModelForSinglePrediction(mLContext, model);

            SaveModel(mLContext, trainingDataView.Schema, model);

            Console.Read();
```

Object Class for Beers

```
    class Beers
    {
        [LoadColumn(0)]
        public float userID { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(1)]
        public string abv { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(2)]
        public string ibu { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(3)]
        public float beerID { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(4)]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(5)]
        public string style { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(6)]
        public float breweryID { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(7)]
        public float ounces { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(8), ColumnName("Label")]
        public float rating { get; set; }




    }
}
```

Comment: How many rows do you have for your training data set?

Comment: @Jon including the headers, the data set is 32 rows.

Comment: I bet that's why. I don't think the data set is big enough to get decent metrics from.

Comment: I can try increasing the data set. I feel like it has something to do with the BuildAndTrainModel() in the last line .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "abvEncoded", "ibuEncoded", "styleEncoded")); It seems like the model may not fully understand the features I am giving it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you would need to one hot encode ABV and IBU. Those are numerical values so they should be able to be used either as is or by normalizing.